# JavaScript Collision Function

Tags: javascript, html, collision

I'm making my first game in HTML5 through a tutorial. The tutorial ended abruptly, but I decided I would finish up the game with things like an end screen and ways to be killed by enemies. The problem, however, is that no matter what I read, I can't seem to figure out this collision function for checking if two rectangles have collided. At the moment, with the current collision function [here](http://jackscode.99k.org/). You can find the specific function itself [here](http://pastebin.com/y0fEBxHm), and the entire program(just in case even though I know you probably won't look at that) [here](http://pastebin.com/QVA5qa0f). I've been reading around like I'm suppose to before I post, but I can't seem to make the collision work just right. Am I doing something tottally wrong or is my logic just off. If anyone could help, I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Ok, sorry about the error, I put in that other function logic as what's below me, but I'm pretty sure it's the same. I was just getting an error before.

```
(!(x1 + w1 < x2) &&
           !(x2 + w2 < x1) &&
           !(y1 + h1 < y2) &&
           !(y2 + h2 < y1))
```

Comment: Your (new) collision function looks correct (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082624/rectangle-intersect-code-is-this-right/6082871#6082871).  Define "work just right".

Comment: Well, the collsion isn't right. It collides sometimes and doesn't stop. I'll put it into the link for the game and you can see what I mean.I'm assuming you mean the code I posted in this post and not the paste bin part.

Comment: Yes, I meant the (original) shorter function - it only takes four comparisons to perform a rectangle intersection test.

Comment: Your javascript code won't run because of an error...

Comment: Ok, I'm pretty sure that if you use the game now it'll be using that function. The problem is it doesn't seem to work right now.

Comment: Sorry, when I tried to use that function it gave me an error. I'm trying to fix it now, sorry, I'm kinda new to JS.

Comment: Ok, I think I fixed it. Let me know if it's still now working.

Comment: If anyone's there, that would be awesome. I could really use help with this.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe can this help :)

```
function collision(a,b)
{
    if(a.x < b.x + b.sprite.width && a.x + a.sprite.width > b.x && a.y < b.y + b.sprite.height && a.y + a.sprite.height > b.y)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```